# Old session showing in Chrome

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, session, drupal-7

I developed a site in Drupal that takes you through several pages to help develop a plan.  The idea is if someone while making the plan moves off to another part of the site and then comes back to the plan their spot will be saved in a session.

It all works fine in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome it doesn't (most times).

When it does work it's because you use the site's links to get back to the plan.  But if you use the back button in the browser you end up  at an older version of the session.  If you hit refresh the the right page loads in.

Why would this older session be loading in? Especially since there is a newer session? Here is the script that loads the current sections content.

```
    $output = array(
        "current" => $_SESSION["order"]["current"],
        "nodes" => $nodes
    );
    $node = node_load($current);
    $nodeView = node_view($node, 'full');
```

Thanks for any help at all.

Comment: clear drupal cache in performance management section

Comment: Thanks.  But that has no effect.  I don't think it has anything to with drupal.

Comment: Maybe you can just implement a small ajax polling in your client side and check if the server has a newer version of the plan. And if it has, notify the user about the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because Chrome seems to cache everything. To fix this I added

```
<?php  
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
?>
```

I had to use "no-store".